# List.remove removes odd elements

Tags: java

It might be something obvious but not able to rationalise the output of this snippet.
Reference: [this](https://github.com/marhan/effective-java-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/effectivejava/examples/chapter07/item41/SetList.java)

```
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (int i = -3; i < 3; i++) {
            set.add(i);
            list.add(i);
        }
        System.out.println("After adding elements:");
        System.out.println(set + " " + list);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            set.remove(i);
            list.remove(i);
        }
        System.out.println("After removing elements:");
        System.out.println(set + " " + list);
    }
}
```

output:

After adding elements:

[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2] [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

After removing elements:

[-3, -2, -1] [-2, 0, 2]

I am expecting:

After removing elements:

[-3, -2, -1] [0, 1, 2]

i.e. list.remove(i) should actually remove 1st ,2nd and 3rd item in the list. fair enough ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You change position of elements in your list when you remove the first, so your code's behavior makes sense:

e.g.

```
for (int i = -3; i < 3; i++) {
    set.add(i);
    list.add(i);
}
System.out.println("After adding elements:");
System.out.println(set + " " + list);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    set.remove(i);
    list.remove(i);
}
```

every time you call list.remove(i), the list is smaller by 1 item, and the item position shifts to the left: the item that was in position 1 goes to position 0 , the one in position 2 goes in position 1, etc...

Use an Iterator to remove elements or List's clear method.

If you want to remove the Integer object based on it's value, change your int to an Integer:

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: +1. I'm just curious, does `set.remove(0)` and `list.remove(0)` inside the loop fix the problem? Or it'll still have an undefined behaviour? (Ugly solution.. but I'm just wondering..)

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I'm thinking that it would.

Answer (score 3):

No, the following line:

```
 set.remove(i);
```

takes the int type you passed and boxes to Integer object ([see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)), then it uses Integer equals() method to determine which element has to be removed. It happens because there is no such method in Set of `remove(int index)`, but only `remove(Object o)` which means the primitive type "somehow" has to be converted to Object, in Java there is a Wrapper type for each primitive types and the "conversion" is called autoboxing. Please note there is also a "phenomenon" called unboxing :).

Answer (score 1):

```
[-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
remove index 0
[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
remove index 1
[-2, 0, 1, 2]
remove index 2
[-2, 0, 2]
```

your positions in the list are changing with each remove. Just remove 3 times the position '0'.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of `Set` you are specifying [the object to remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) and hence it actually **removes values** `0`, `1` and `2` from the set. Hence you get the remaining elements as result.

In the case of `List` you are specifying [the index of object to remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29) and hence it actually **removes values at indices** `0`, `1` and `2` from the list. Hence you get the remaining elements as result. It works as follows:

```
Initially (i=0): [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
                   ^
                   X 
Step 1 (i=1): [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
                    ^
                    X
Step 2 (i=2): [-2, 0, 1, 2]
                      ^
                      X
Result:       [-2, 0, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ever imagined doing it functional programming way?

//make sure you are adding static imports for both matcher and lambdaj to simulate below code

```
import static ch.lambdaj.Lambda.*;
import static org.test.matcher.MatcherFactory.*;   //this can be anything

    List<Integer> original = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6);

    List<Integer> oddList = filter(odd, original);

   for(int s : oddList){
    System.out.println(s);
    }
   //and it prints out   1,3,5
```

And make a class called MatcherFactory.java

```
public class MatcherFactory {

    public static Matcher<Integer> odd = new Predicate<Integer>() {
        public boolean apply(Integer item) {
                return item % 2 == 1;
            }
    };

   //put as many as matchers you want and reuse them
}
```

You can download the lambdaj library from here

https://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures

and see more examples